# Nav Component not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Nav component is not working,its not expanding to show the available options on screen sizes less then 768px.This is my code below.

```
 <nav class="nav navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-
            toggle="collapse" data-taget="#navbar" >          

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                     placeholder="Search" />
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit
                </button>
            </form>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Please post your full navbar code.

Comment: @grusl83 Hi I have updated the whole code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Subscribe</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here's the working fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/8nyor7xk/

Comment: Thanks Man @grusl83